# Is there a function to break ID Field into Octets and check field values based on Octets(MS Access)?

Tags: sql, database, ms-access

I am trying to breakdown the ID field (eg. AAABBB123 as AAA BBB and 123) and compare with another field in the Table to check if it has the desired value. (if first octet is AAA, then the other field should have value1, if the first octet is ZZZ then the other field should have value2) If the values don't match I am trying to return those records.

This is what I have tried so far.

```
SELECT LEFT([SUB_ID], 3) AS TrimmedColumn
FROM Table1
```

I am able to get the First Octet using this but I don't know how to compare with another field and get the record that don't match with the desired value.

> DETAILED PROBLEM DESC:

Let's say first octet is AAA, then the field "A" should have value 1, if it doesn't have the value 1 I need to return those records and so on.

Similarly, if suppose the first octet is ZZZ, then the field "A" should have value2, if it doesn't I need to return those records and so on.

I would also like to do the same with the second octet and a different field "B" to check if it has the desired value based on the Octet.

[This is an example table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/reQO6.png)

Am I heading in the right direction? Is there a function to do it? How should I optimize my solution to this problem?

Comment: How many combinations of each octet are there? Are all 26 letters of alphabet in any combination used for parts 1 and 2? That's a lot of possibilities! Will probably need a table that defines this data association and maybe even VBA procedure.

Comment: Thanks for the comment! The problem I am trying to solve has 10 unique octets in each parts of 1 and 2, the letters of alphabets here is just an example. Each Octet is associated with a particular value that a field should have. And yes, I did create a mapping table between Octets and the desired values but I don't know how to proceed further.

Comment: Now I have to ask, why bother even having fields A, B, C when the required associated value can be pulled from the 'mapping' table?

Comment: Sorry that I couldn't get back soon. It was actually an existing database of a charity in which they already have some information. But due to existing bad design, there were wrong entries in the table. This is just like an error catching mechanism that I am trying to build without actually changing the contents myself. And hence I came up with this problem statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Build query that extracts desired part and join to mapping table. If data field does not match value in mapping table, return record. I expect you will need to do 3 queries. Here is one example:

```
SELECT Map.*, T1.* FROM Map INNER JOIN (
   SELECT Table1.ID, Table1.A, Left([SUB_ID],3) AS T FROM Table1) AS T1 
ON T1.T = Map.Oct 
WHERE T1.A <> Map.V;
```

Use Mid() function to parse the other parts.

Comment: Thanks much! This is exactly what I needed help with. I went as far as Inner Join. I was able to get the exact opposite of what I wanted (Pulling the records in which the field has desired value matching with the mapping table, instead of pulling all the records that didn't match.) I was able to get (A ∩ B) but I wanted 1- (A ∩ B). This fixes it.